# Custom menu first item active state in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would like to put the first custom menu item active, so there needs to be an "active" class. How can I do that?
This is my html:

```
<nav class="secondmenu">
    <div class="menu-captain-crew-container">
        <ul id="menu-captain-crew" class="secondnav">
         <li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-35"><a title="Captain" href="#Captain">Captain</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-36"><a title="Chief Stewardess" href="#chief-stewardess">Chief Stewardess</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-37"><a title="Chief Engineer" href="#chief-engineer">Chief engineer</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-38"><a title="Purser" href="#purser">Purser</a></li>

        </ul>
   </div>           
 </nav>
```

And this is the code I use to get my custom menu in my template:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Captain & Crew', 'menu_class' => 'secondnav')); ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Appearance > Menus in the WordPress admin area.  Then open "Screen Options" and make sure "CSS Classes" is checked.  "Screen Options" is the tab in the very top right corner of your admin screen.   See the screenshot below.

[image]

Then open the menu item that you wish to add the class to and type your class name in the "CSS Classes" input.  Make sure to save your menu changes before exiting the menu screen.  See screenshot below.

[image]

This will add the class to the wrapping `<li></li>` of the menu item you entered the class for.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, always forget to open up the screen options for some reason.

Comment: You're welcome, sometimes is the easiest things that stump you.  Happens to me all the time.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was getting so freaking frustrated wondering where this setting had gone!! THANK YOU!! :D